# Not able to edit file detail page in community builder

Tags: community

[image]

I want to edit file detail page to remove tabs. But I am not able to edit that page, it is throwing some error. I am not able to understand what is that error. Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems that you don't have any files uploaded in your org or has access to. Hence the page cannot load the view on the page. Add at least one file and then try again.

Comment: I already have a file in the org even though it is showing same error.